# Updating child in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How to avoid deleting and re-inserting of child records ?

For Ex : I have 10 rows in child table and i want to add 11th row. But looks like hibernate is deleting all the old child records and re-inserting new one.

Please help.

My Code looks like this

```
     @Entity
     @Table(name = "ACCESS_GROUP")
   public class AccessGroup implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false ,unique =true)
private String group_name;


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@Cascade (value=org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
@JoinColumn(name="ID", nullable=false)
@OrderBy("im")
private Set<GroupIm> imSet = null;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "accessGroup")
private Set<accessGroupList> accessGroupLists;
```

.....}

and the child is like this

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCESS_GROUP_IM")
public class AccessGroupIm implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String im;  


public accessGroupIm() {
    // empty constructor for hibernate
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getIm() {
    return im;
}

public void setIm(String im) {
    this.im = im;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((im == null) ? 0 : im.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    accessGroupIm other = (accessGroupIm) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    if (im == null) {
        if (other.im != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!im.equals(other.im))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

}

Thanks

Comment: Hibernate behaviour is highly configuration and code driven. So, can you give the configuration details and also the code where you are trying to do add a new row?

Comment: do the children have their own entity ids?  if not, i don't believe hibernate can do individual updates and must update the entire set.  if you you give the children their own ids, this problem can be avoided.

Comment: I have an ID field in the child. Also i update my question. please have a look

Comment: How did you implement equals and hashCode?

Comment: Updated the question...please check

Comment: How does this code even compile?? Um, this: private Set<accessGroupList> accessGroupLists;
is wrong.

Comment: How are u performing this update?

Answer (score 0):

Like  jtahlborn said, you probably forgeting to put ID on the entity, so hibernate have no other choice but remove all and then inset it again for any change you make. Take a look in this link for more information:

http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/why-hibernate-does-delete-all-then-re.html

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to add the child entity under parent entity as follows

> - The following code would be used to add a new Child:

```
    Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
    Child c = new Child();
    c.setParent(p);
    p.getChildren().add(c);
    session.save(c);
    session.flush();
```

> - You could also create an addChild() method of Parent.

```
 public void addChild(Child c) {
        c.setParent(this);
        children.add(c);
 }
```

then the code to add a Child looks like this:

```
Parent p = (Parent) session.load(Parent.class, pid);
    Child c = new Child();
    p.addChild(c);
    session.save(c);
    session.flush();
```

**EDIT:**
   You have used both the *CascadeTypes* (`javax.persistence.CascadeType and org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType`) in your code. I would suggest first study the difference between them in [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/cascade-jpa-hibernate-annotation-common-mistake/) then use proper *CascadeType*  as per your requirement.